# Serving a website from a local device that is accessible from the public IP address of a self-hosted remote VPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, webserver, self-hosting

I'm self-hosting a VPN service (OpenVPN) on a remote server that has a static IP address.  I got my local devices to connect to it with no problem and I'm able to access the apps I host locally from the private IP address assigned to my local devices by the VPN service with no issue.

What I want to do is the following:

I want to serve a web app (let's say on port 8080) on a local device that I have at home and have that web app accessible to anyone on the internet from the VPN's public IP address (i.e., from `http(s)://$VPN_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:8080`).

I opened port 80, 443 and 8080 on the remote VPN server (using `ufw`),
but I was still not able to access the website using the public IP address of the remote VPN server.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Seems the issue is still in the firewall config. I suggest to check with https://portchecker.co/ if 8080 is really available from Internet. Use pubic IP of VPN server there.

Comment: You need to add a port forwarding rule

Comment: @mashuptwice I have  already done that, it didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Simply opening the port is not enough, you also need to tell your VPN server where to route the packets.

[DNAT](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html) should solve this easily.

Comment: that didnt work